# Occurring symbol per line

Tags: c, arrays, statements

I want to get the occurrence of the symbol ';' for each line of this C program. I type the name of the file Source.c and try to count the occurring symbol, but i am getting the value for ALL of the ';' for each line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>/* For exit() function */

int main()
{
   char file_name[150];
   FILE *file2 = 0;

   gets(file_name);

   {
      int rows = 1;//broq na vsichki redove

      int dotcoma[150];
      int j;
      int c=0;

      file2 = fopen(file_name, "r");//otvarq faial za chetene
      if (file2 == NULL){
         printf("Cannot open %s\n", file_name);
         exit(2);
      }//if

      for (j = 0; j < 150; j++)
         dotcoma[j]=0;

      do{
         c = fgetc(file2);
         if (c == '\n') rows++;

         if (';' == c)

            dotcoma[rows-1] ++;



      } while (c != EOF && rows <= 150);//chete do kraq na faila

      if (ferror(file2)){
         printf("Error reading file.\n");

      }//if

      printf("The number of the symbols on a row ");
      printf("Row %d: %f\n", j + 1, (float)dotcoma[j]);

   }

   if (fclose(file2) == EOF){
      printf("Cannot close %s\n", file_name);

   }
   _getche();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: one obvious flaw: What if your file has over 150 lines?

Comment: Display the result for all 150 individual lines.

Comment: I believe the printfs are called only once after everything is read. Not really sure what the goal was

Comment: do--while loop is for reading untill the end of the file. Why I'd need a break statement ?

Comment: This code has a memory error: the `for` loop that uses `j` stops at `j==150`. Later, after the file has been read and counted, `j` is used to index out-of-bounds into the `dotcoma` array. So, whatever it is printing, it's just some random memory

Comment: Your `do..while()` loop terminates when `c` is `EOF` only *after* you use `c` in the loop.  Try a `while` loop with `while ((c = fgetc(file2)) != EOF)` and get rid of the `fgetc()` in the loop body.  Or, add `if (c == EOF) break;` after `fgetc()`.

Comment: **Never, never, never** use `gets`. It is no longer part of the C standard due to lack of security and potential for exploitation. Use `fgets`, `getline` or `scanf` instead.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - First the words `Never` & `Always` should be used with more care.  Second, if you are going to make such adamant statements, try to qualify them.  The C environments I have to maintain still use compilers written against C standards that include the `gets` function.  Specify what C standard you are referring to.

Comment: If you want to use `gets` by all means do so, but know the risks associated with it. The **never** applies in any sane world of coding with C. Does that mean **you** cannot use it -- of course not. Are you suggesting that as a general rule you **should** use `gets` or that it is **safe** to use `gets`?

Comment: @chux, read my comment (4 above) that started this odyssey. Quote "**Never, never, never** use `gets`. It is no longer part of the C standard...." It wasn't meant to apply to the "knowledgeable" coders, it was meant for the new user. You guys are way, way too literal.

Comment: @David C. Rankin  I did mis-read a key element of your comments. Taking down that and later this comment.

Answer (score 1):

You have almost everything in place. The only change you need to make is put the line

```
     printf("Row %d: %f\n", j + 1, (float)dotcoma[j]);
```

in a `for` loop and change the format from `%f` to `%d`.

```
  printf("The number of the symbols on a row \n");
  for (j = 0; j < rows; j++)
  {
     printf("Row %d: %d\n", j + 1, dotcoma[j]);
  }
```

You must make sure `rows` stays at 150 or below. Otherwise, you'll end up accessing the array `dotcoma` out of bounds. One way to do that would be to use:

```
  do{
     c = fgetc(file2);
     if (c == '\n') rows++;

     if (';' == c)
        dotcoma[rows-1] ++;

  } while (c != EOF && rows <= 150);//chete do kraq na faila
```

Comment: @chux, thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer to fix the problem at the source.

Comment: Not clear why your answer had an undeserved down-vote.

Comment: @chux, it's one of those things many SO users do. Everyone has their reasons and I have learned to ignore them when they are not accompanied by constructive feedback.

Comment: @RSahu Still does not work, it does not change the results i am geting. Thank you for your given time though.

Comment: @RSahu Maybe i should use an entierly different approach. To write every line into a string and anylise every line (string) by line for the symbol ';'.

Comment: @IliqnLalov This solution solves the problem I see. I'd encourage you to edit your question to show your code after making [R Sahu](http://stackoverflow.com/users/434551/r-sahu)'s suggested edits, and we'll see if we can identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have made great progress. It counts now for the frequency for every ';' for a line and wanted to add a new symbol frequency aswell '.' in my case, but it says that there is Stack arround varriable. Here it is the code working, but just without the second symbol frequency comma++ counter. Can someone give advice how to fix it ?

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /* Да си изключа предупрежденията*/
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>/* For exit() function */

int main()
{
    char file_name[1000];
    FILE *file2 = 0;

    gets(file_name);
    int rows = 1;//broq na vsichki redove
    int dotcoma[150];//broq na ;
    int coma[150];//broq na .
    int j;
    char c;

    file2 = fopen(file_name, "r");//otvarq faial za chetene
    if (file2 == NULL){
        printf("Cannot open %s\n", file_name);
        exit(2);
    }//if

    for (j = 0; j<150; j++)
        dotcoma[j] = 0;
    coma[j] = 0;
    do{
        c = fgetc(file2);
        if (c == '\n') rows++;
        else{
            if (c == ';')
            dotcoma[rows - 1]++;
            if (c == '.')
            coma[rows-1]++;
        }
    } while (c != EOF);//chete do kraq na faila


    if (ferror(file2)){
        printf("Error reading file.\n");
        exit(2);
    }//if

    printf("The number of the symbols on a row / the number of all symbols: ");
    for (j = 0; j<rows; j++){
        printf("Row %d: %f  %f\n", j + 1, (float)dotcoma[j], coma[j]);

    }
    _getche();
    if (fclose(file2) == EOF){
        printf("Cannot close %s\n", file_name);
        exit(2);

        _getche();
        return 0;
    }
}
```